# Equivalent of setTimeout and setInterval function in Script#

Tags: c#, javascript, script#

How to use `setTimeout()` and `setInterval` method in C# with Script#?

For example, how to write: `setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SetTimeout()` and `SetInterval()` are part of the `Script` class (or `Window` for previous versions of Script# < 0.8). You use them like this with an inline delegate:

```
int intervalid = Script.SetInterval(delegate { Window.Alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Or you can write an explicit handler function:

```
Script.SetTimeout(TimeoutHandler, 3000);

void TimeoutHandler() {
    Window.Alert("Hello");
}
```

To discard the timer interval later you can use `ClearInterval()`:

```
Script.ClearInterval(intervalid);
```

Comment: I don't see this methods in Script class. What namespaces they define in?

Comment: I fixed your slips (you mix `Window` with `Script`).

Comment: Your edits are wrong. SetTimeout() and SetInterval() are clearly part of the script class. See: https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/cc/src/Core/CoreLib/Script.cs

Comment: Starting with 0.8 they will be on the Script class. They used to be on Window... but thats incorrect. For example, these methods are available in node.js as well... in reality they're defined on the global object (which happens to be window in browsers).

Comment: @NikhilK, I was in doubt, why these functions in **Window** class in my Script# library and in **Script** class in aschoenebeck code. Thank you for your elucidation. aschoenebeck, could you correct your answer with NikhilK remakrs (your code is suitable to version of Script# >= 0.8)?

Comment: Oh I see. I've only checked the git master and cc branches, not older versions. I've edited the answer to point to `Window` for previous versions. I'm assuming 0.8 will be released soon.